# Reshape data.frame with multiple headers

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rows, reshape

My data.frame looks like this:

| name | country1 | country1 | country2 | country2 | country3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | code1 | code1 | code2 | code2 | code3 |
|  | sector1 | sector2 | sector1 | sector2 | sector1 |
| country1 | ### | ### | ### | ### | ### |
| country2 | ### | ### | ### | ### | ### |
| country3 | ### | ### | ### | ### | ### |
| country4 | ### | ### | ### | ### | ### |

where ## are numbers.

I want to reshape it like this:

| name | country | code | sector | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| country1 | country2 | code 2 | sector 1 | ### |
| country1 | country2 | code 2 | sector 2 | ### |
| country1 | country3 | code 3 | sector 1 | ### |
| country1 | country3 | code 3 | sector 2 | ### |
| country2 | country2 | code 2 | sector 2 | ### |
| country3 | country1 | code 1 | sector 1 | ### |
| country4 | country3 | code 3 | sector 1 | ### |

How can I tidy up my data set? My problem is that the raw data come with this weird format in which there are multiple headers, so that I cannot simply go with `pivot_longer`.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide your data in a reproducible format using `dput` ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: You can download the data from : https://worldmrio.com/unctadgvc/ . It is the third dataset available.  I opened the .txt file with `read.delim` and `sep = "/t"`

Comment: I made a final attempt to solve your problem. Take a look at the edit at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are better ways but you can use `dplyr`:

```r
data %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("country"), ~ paste0(.x, collapse = "_")),
         name = "name") %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("country"), ~ paste0(cur_column(), "_", .x))) %>% 
  {`colnames<-`(data, unlist(.))} %>% 
  slice(3:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("country"), 
               names_to = c("country", "code", "sector"),
               names_pattern="(country\\d+).+(code\\d+).+(sector\\d+)") %>%
  filter(name != country)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   name     country  code  sector  value
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>
 1 country1 country2 code2 sector1 ###  
 2 country1 country2 code2 sector2 ###  
 3 country1 country3 code3 sector1 ###  
 4 country2 country1 code1 sector1 ###  
 5 country2 country1 code1 sector2 ###  
 6 country2 country3 code3 sector1 ###  
 7 country3 country1 code1 sector1 ###  
 8 country3 country1 code1 sector2 ###  
 9 country3 country2 code2 sector1 ###  
10 country3 country2 code2 sector2 ###  
11 country4 country1 code1 sector1 ###  
12 country4 country1 code1 sector2 ###  
13 country4 country2 code2 sector1 ###  
14 country4 country2 code2 sector2 ###  
15 country4 country3 code3 sector1 ###
```

Note: I filtered for `name != country` since in your expected output those rows with matching aren't present.

**Edit**

One last try:

```r
data %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  rename(name = X) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(-name), ~ paste0(.x, collapse = "_")),
         name = "name") %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(-name), ~ paste0(cur_column(), "_", .x))) %>% 
  {`colnames<-`(data, unlist(.))} %>% 
  slice(3:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(-name), 
               names_to = c("country", "code", "sector"),
               names_pattern="(country\\d+).+(code\\d+).+(sector\\d+)") %>%
  filter(name != country)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the dataset I posted is just a stylized one. The original one has actual country names as labels ("Afghanistan, Albania..), so I can't use `starts_with` to group labels. I posted the link to the original dataset in the comments to my question.

Comment: Replace `starts_with("country")` by `c(-name)`.

Comment: In this case an error occurs: `Can't subset columns that don't exist`

Comment: Your first column is named "name" like in your example?

Comment: It was named "X" and I tried with `c(-data$X)`. Now it is named "name" and I tried with`c(-data$name)`. Same result

Comment: You don't need `data$`, since this refers to the original data.frame without any transformations. Just use `X` and `name`

Comment: Just a hint: Your sample data should represent your original data. You can show your data by using `dput(head(data))`. Usally people (including me) on SO don't want to click on external links.

Comment: Again an error: 
`Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [14841] must be the same length as the vector [14840]`

Comment: I know, I am sorry. I tried with `dput` but the dataset has 193 observations of 14840 variables, so the output of that function was unreadable.